Figuring out how to do Voltage Divider
Here in the Ac analysis section of the CC amplifier we're getting the Gain (Av)
We used voltage divider method for Vb/Vs; I was confused as to why when getting Vb(voltage at base node ) why we didn't say: Rb // re only in the numerator, why are the resistors (re + RL') included for the voltage divider, I assumed they have nothing to do with the node 'b'



what have you tried. Show your work.

I added my answer. Thanks for the reply

You are right the correct one is
$$\frac{V_B}{V_S} = \frac{R_{IN}}{R_S + R_{IN}} = \frac{R_B||[(\beta +1)(r_e + R_L')]}{R_S + R_B||[ (\beta +1)(r_e + R_L') ] }$$
